# How do I share screens on 2 devices on a different network in Python?

Tags: python

I have a script that allows me to share screens on the same network in python but I want to be able to do it from different networks. Can somebody show me how?

My code for receiver.py is:

```
from vidstream import StreamingServer
import threading
receiver = StreamingServer('127.0.0.1', 9999)
t = threading.Thread(target=receiver.start_server)
t.start()

while input("") != 'STOP':
    continue
receiver.stop_server()
```

My code for client.py (PC I am viewing) is:

```
from vidstream import ScreenShareClient
import threading
sender = ScreenShareClient('127.0.0.1', 9999)
t = threading.Thread(target=sender.start_stream)
t.start()

while input("") != 'STOP':
    continue
receiver.stop_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the IP address from the loopback address to your IP on the local network, and then forward those ports in the router.

Since **192.168.x.x** (class C IP address) is often used by home networks, we will take the following example IP, but you could find this out through `ifconfig` on linux, or `ipconfig` in windows.

```
StreamingServer('192.168.2.1', 9999)
```

-> Forward the ports in the router and/or firewall.

-> Find out your public IP (https://whatsmyip.org)

Then on your client, enter your public IP, and the port to connect to your server:

```
ScreenShareClient('YOUR_PUBLIC_IP', 9999)
```

Comment: When I run this I get “the requested address is not valid in its context”

Comment: What exactly are you running? I recommend you learn a little about networking before using sockets in python.